# Non-linearity of neural network classification

Tags: neural-networks, logistic

Why is it that logistic regression is considered a linear classifier, but a neural network with a sigmoid activation function and sigmoid output layer is considered non-linear? I am aware that logistic regression is considered linear because its inputs are a linear combination of the original inputs, but couldn't the same be said of the neural network example?

Answer (score 12):

A neural network with a single sigmoid neuron is also a linear classifier when the output is thresholded for classification. But, more than one layer produces a non-linear one because the decision rule can't be written in the following form:
$$\sum w_i x_i+b>\tau$$
where $\tau$ is threshold, $w_i$ are learnable weights and $x_i$ are features. This is why logistic regression is referred as a linear classifier.

Comment: Maybe to elaborate a little:
When talking about the (non)linearity of models, the combination of weights is considered. The use of non-linear function does not lead necessarily to non linear models. (although they are needed to "create" them). In case of a logistic regression only a single sigmoid function is used. But all weights are added linearly before that transformation. In a neural network  at least two non-linear transformations are used. No you have a scenario where the combinations in not linear.

Comment: So, a neural network with 2 sigmoid units is considered to be non-linear simply because the input to the second sigmoid unit is non-linear due to the non-linear activation of the inputs?

Comment: @terribleprogrammer, this has to do with how many hidden layers there are. In the case of logistic regression, there is zero. If there is at least one, you get nonlinearity.